# How to Import Existing Tizen TV project in the IDE

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am just starting with Tizen TV SDK and have a very basic query. 
I am using the Tizen SDK - 2.4.0_Rev5 on Windows 7 64 bit. 
I downloaded the following Sample Project from the git repository for Tizen TV SDK:
https://github.com/SamsungDForum/AVPlaySample

My question is how to import this project into the IDE.

I tried File->Import->Tizen->Web Projects and Web applications File and gave the path to the root folder of the downloaded source code. However, I get a message that no projects are found to be imported.

I had earlier created a new project in the IDE. Now if I close that project from the IDE and try to import it using File->Import->Tizen...., it works.

The only difference I can notice is that while opening the project I had earlier created and built, the project has a .wgt file. 
So is that the reason why the second projects opens and the first one which I downloaded does not? 
How do I import the projects which do not have the .wgt file ?
Is there some step which I am missing here?

Thanks and Regards,
Archit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The github project is not a complete Tizen project, that is why when you are trying to import, it is showing no project.

You can see the folder structure difference below:

[image]

I would suggest you to create a new project in tizen IDE and then copy and paste the files from the github project.

Cheers!

Comment: After working with this IDE for the past year, this is the only way I've found to do it as well.